# Mean.js - Getting ArticleID through to comment Controller

Tags: javascript, meanjs

I had a function working correctly to show only comments relating to the article by having the ArticleID as part of the Post collection and using it as a parameter. However ive changed something and now it wont send the value through as  a parameter to the function.

**comments.server.controller.js**

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {


     console.log( JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 2));


    Comment.find(

        **{articleID : req.params.article._id}** Possibly the problem

    )
        .sort('-created')
        //.populate('user', 'displayName')
        .exec(function(err, comments) {

        if (err) {

            return res.status(400).send({

                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });

        } else {

            res.jsonp(comments);
        }
    });
};
```

If i take out the Parameters it displays them all fine but gives a 500 error when its there. How do i check the value of req.params.article._id? Console.log doesn't seem to work here.

maybe im calling the wrong variable. Id like to get the articleID of the Article which the comments are on. Both on the same page with controller covering both.

**Comment Collection**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55cf17939562e1d005cfb369"),
"user" : ObjectId("55c8cea0c78fc80c04e8c21a"),
"details" : "Sample Comment",
"articleID" : "55ce84516706bb742890a6ba",
"created" : ISODate("2015-08-15T10:42:27.521Z"),
"userName" : "Joe Bloggs",
"__v" : 0
```

Comment: `console.log` should work if you put it as the first line of the `list` function - try `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 2))` and check to make sure the `article` and its `_id` are as expected

Comment: What does your database model look like?

Comment: It has the articleID in there fine when the comment is posted. Lets say i change the parameter to { articleID" : '55ce84516706bb742890a6ba'  } then it returns the correct comments for the article so its the req.params.article._id which is wrong coming into the function.

Comment: @Robbie It still doesnt seem to log to console. Ive edited the Post with what ive done. bear in mind im new to Javascript coming from Java so its probably something silly im doing. have i add the console.log correctly?

Comment: Ok so it is printing a log now and its showing the params as an empty array. How is the articleID actually sent through as a parameter? Where is it assigned?